# How to create a list of words from custom elements?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I want to make a list of words in a text file from custom elements:

```
element1:
word1
word2
word3

element2:
word4
word5

element3:
word6
word7
```

I want each to be made of a combination of the words in elements 1,2,3, for example:

```
word1word4word6
word1word5word6
word1word4word7
word1word5word7
```

and so and so forth until I have all the combinations of words of all elements 1,2,3 in a list. How can  I do that in a shell script or python script? I am using Linux.

Comment: With `bash`: `printf "%s\n" {word1,word2,word3}{word4,word5}{word6,word7}`?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Check the output of something like echo {a..c}{w..z} and you will find that permutations in groups of 3 is your answer. No need for programing. Just use bash braces as suggested by Cyrus.

Comment: Is the number of `elementX:` always 3?

Comment: Are the elements in a single text file?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a pure programming question here with nothing specific to Linux or Unix, but here's an (untested) code to begin with:

```
#!/bin/bash
element1=( "word1" "word2" "word3" )
element2=( "word4" "word5" )
element3=( "word6" "word7" )
for i in "${element1[@]}"; do
  for j in "${element2[@]}"; do
    for k in "${element3[@]}"; do
      printf "%s%s%s\n" "$i" "$j" "$k"
    done
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using pure `Python` and `slice`s:

```
element1 = ( 'word1', 'word2', 'word3' )
element2 = ( 'word4', 'word5' )
element3 = ( 'word6', 'word7' )

for el1 in element1:
    for el2 in element2:
        for el3 in element3:
            print(el1 + el2 + el3)
```

### Using pure `bash` and `array`s:

```
#!/bin/bash

element1=( 'word1' 'word2' 'word3' )
element2=( 'word4' 'word5' )
element3=( 'word6' 'word7' )

for el1 in "${element1[@]}"; do
    for el2 in "${element2[@]}"; do
        for el3 in "${element3[@]}"; do
            echo "$el1$el2$el3"
        done
    done
done
```

### As `POSIX` shell, taking advantage of shell's *word spliting* on `string`s:

```
#!/bin/sh

element1="word1 word2 word3"
element2="word4 word5"
element3="word6 word7"
for el1 in $element1; do
    for el2 in $element2; do
        for el3 in $element3; do
            echo "$el1$el2$el3"
        done
    done
done
```

### Output

```
word1word4word6
word1word4word7
word1word5word6
word1word5word7
word2word4word6
word2word4word7
word2word5word6
word2word5word7
word3word4word6
word3word4word7
word3word5word6
word3word5word7
```

Comment: Note that leaving variables unquoted also performs globbing, so if any of those words may contain globbing wildcard characters, you'd need a `set -o noglob` beforehand. `echo` should also be avoided unless you can guarantee the words won't contain backslash characters and won't start with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
element1=(
  word1
  word2
  word3
)
element2=(word4 word5)
element3=(word6 word7)

combinations=( $^element1$^element2$^element3 )
```

Which you can print on one column with

```
print -rC1 -- $combinations
```

or

```
printf %s $^combinations$'\n'
```

`$^element1$^element2$^element3` can be simplified to `$element1$element2$element3` if you set the `rcexpandparam` option (`set -o rcexpandparam`) beforehand.

Same with `fish` which expands arrays the same `rc`-style¹ way by default.

```
set element1 word1 word2 word3
set element2 wort4 word5
set element3 word6 word7
set combinations $element1$element2$element3
echo -ns -- $combinations\n
```

---

<sup>¹ well in `rc`, arrays don't expand exactly like that. `a=(a b); echo x$a` outputs `xa xb`, but `echo $a$a` outputs `aa bb`, not `aa ab ba bb` and for arrays of different size other than 1, you get an error, so you couldn't use it here.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and ARGIND:

```
$ awk '
    { words[ARGIND][$0] }
    END {
        for ( i in words[1] )
            for ( j in words[2] )
                for ( k in words[3] )
                    print i j k
    }
' element1 element2 element3
word1word4word6
word1word4word7
word1word5word6
word1word5word7
word2word4word6
word2word4word7
word2word5word6
word2word5word7
word3word4word6
word3word4word7
word3word5word6
word3word5word7
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] { words1[$0] }
    FILENAME == ARGV[2] { words2[$0] }
    FILENAME == ARGV[3] { words3[$0] }
    END {
        for ( i in words1 )
            for ( j in words2 )
                for ( k in words3 )
                    print i j k
    }
' element1 element2 element3
word1word4word6
word1word4word7
word1word5word6
word1word5word7
word2word4word6
word2word4word7
word2word5word6
word2word5word7
word3word4word6
word3word4word7
word3word5word6
word3word5word7
```

Alternatively, using any awk that supports `delete array` (if yours doesn't then use `split("",array)` instead) for any number of input files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    currs[$0]
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    delete prevs
    for ( str in currs ) {
        prevs[str]
    }
    delete currs
}
{
    for ( str in prevs ) {
        currs[str $0]
    }
}
END {
    for ( str in currs ) {
        print str
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk element1 element2 element3
word2word4word7
word3word5word6
word3word5word7
word1word5word6
word3word4word6
word1word5word7
word3word4word7
word2word5word6
word2word5word7
word1word4word6
word1word4word7
word2word4word6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my %h = slurp.split("\n\n", :skip-empty)    \
                    .map( *.split("\n", :skip-empty))   \
                    .map: {.[0] => .[1..*]};            \
            .say for [X] %h.map: *.value;'   file
```

This solution is useful for files that fit into memory as it `slurp`s the file in all at once, newlines and all. After `slurp`ing, the text is `split` into paragraphs on `\n\n` two-consecutive newlines. To handle "paragraphs" separated by two ***or more*** consecutive newlines, use `.split(/ \n ** 2..* /, :skip-empty)`.

Once appropriately split into paragraphs, each is then again split on single `\n` newlines to get a key/value structure, which is stored in `%h` hash. The first line becomes the key (index `.[0]`), while the remaining lines become the values (index `.[1..*]`).

Finally, Raku has a `X` cross-product infix operator, which returns combinations of elements when given LHS and RHS lists of values. Many (all?) infix operators can be transformed into a ***reduction meta-operator*** by simply surrounding them with square brackets and placing them at the head of a list. So `[X] %h.map: *.value;` creates a list of hash `values` organized by key, for which the combinatoric cross-product is generated and output.

Sample Input:

```
element1:
word1
word2
word3

element2:
word4
word5

element3:
word6
word7
```

Sample Output:

```
(word1 word6 word4)
(word1 word6 word5)
(word1 word7 word4)
(word1 word7 word5)
(word2 word6 word4)
(word2 word6 word5)
(word2 word7 word4)
(word2 word7 word5)
(word3 word6 word4)
(word3 word6 word5)
(word3 word7 word4)
(word3 word7 word5)
```

Because hashes randomize in Raku, you'll get the requisite 3 'words' per line, but these words will be in random order. Also (unlike at least one other answer), this Raku answer tolerates duplicate 'words'.

Note: to generate the exact output desired my the OP, change the last line to `join` without spaces and out`put`:

`.join.put for [X] %h.map: *.value;`

Or, more simply (using `~` tilde-concatenation):

`.put for [X~] %h.map: *.value;`

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators
https://docs.raku.org/routine/X
https://raku.org